# bootstrap div breaking on mobile iphone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I've got a bootstrap website working perfectly on desktop and (I thought) mobile because when I drag my desktop browser size down to be super skinny, the site displays perfectly...however on an actual mobile device, it does not. The top div (jumbotron) breaks and the background color flows down into the next section.

Can someone please take a look and offer their opinion? I'm a novice coder at best and have been trying to troubleshoot for a while now with no luck.

Website is www.artyst-tyrant.com

HTML:

```
<body>  

<div class="jumbotron" id="top">

<div class="video">
<video class="video-background visible-lg" no-controls autoplay loop src="img/dino-video.mp4?dl=0" poster="img/dino.png"></video></div>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('video');
</script>
<![endif]-->

<div class="container content">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Artyst Tyrant</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#intro" class="smoothScroll">Intro <span class="sr-only \">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#experience" class="smoothScroll">Experience</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="row text-center text-container">
<h1>creating inspiring brands</h1>
<h2>to empower intelligent business</h2>
<h5>Isn’t it time the quality of your brand matched the quality of your business?</h5>

<a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg smoothScroll">Get Started Now</a>

</div></div>
</div>
<!--End Jumbotron-->
```

CSS:

```
/*logo */

.navbar-brand {
width:229px;
height:108px;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 0 60px;
background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
z-index: 5; 

}


/*nav bar */

.navbar-default {
background:none;
border:none;
z-index: 5; 

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:2px;
color:#ecf0f1;
padding: 15px 0;
text-align:center;
z-index: 5; 

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:focus {
color:#e5c6f1;
text-decoration:underline;
z-index: 5; 
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:focus {
background:none;
outline: 0;
color:#fff; 
font-weight:700;
z-index: 5; 

}

.navbar-toggle {
border:none;
margin-top:0;
margin-right:0;
width:32px;
height:32px;
text-align: center;
 z-index: 5; 

}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {    
background:none;
outline: none;
z-index: 5; 

}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
border:none;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow:none;
z-index: 5; 

}

/* end navigation */


/* end navigation */


.jumbotron {
background: url(../img/dino.png) no-repeat #8e44ad;
background-size:cover;
max-height:900px;
margin:0;
position:relative;
z-index: 2; 
background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-attachment: fixed;

}

.video-background { /* class name used in javascript too */
width: 100%; /* width needs to be set to 100% */
height: 100%; /* height needs to be set to 100% */
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: -2;
}

video { display: block; 
opacity: .4; filter: alpha(opacity=40); -moz-opacity: .4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* for IE only */
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;

}


.jumbotron:after {
background: url(../img/stripes.png) center repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 1;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 900px;
z-index: -1; 
content: '';
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Like I said, dragging it down to mobile width in the desktop browser shows the mobile perfectly, but look at it on an iPhone and the top div breaks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Next time you want to emulate a mobile device, open developer tools in Chrome. From there you can select from a list of default devices (and screen resolutions) or specify your own.

Answer (score 0):

I also shrink the size of the browser to emulate it (hack it) as a mobile device. In your case, the width is off. You should design for minimum 320px (iphone standard width size). Then progressively develop for larger widths and anomolies (andrioid and other varying sizes).

I launched your website in firefox and at 320px I get a scroll bar. This scroll bar is a problem. Either the mobile browser will expand or throw out some inconsistent layout pattern.

Test @ 320px.

Edit:

Remove or resize any `<div class="row"></div>`. Do not use negative margins. They are creating the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: The site is built on bootstrap, which uses <div class="row"></div> as a fundamental part of the system. Can you clarify?  I was able to fix the color issue but the site is still misaligned (what should be centered items are pushed right.) I was using negative margins to try to correct this. Also, i just noticed that objects I assigned to be hidden on mobile are showing in safari mobile but not other mobile browsers. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Recreate the css declaration from row (if you need them) only for desktop and remove them for mobile. The negative margins are killing your page layout in mobile.